# How to add git to Docker curlimage?

Tags: docker, curl, docker-container

In my YAML script I use a `curlimages/curl` for a task there:

```
upload:
  rules:
    - if: $CO_BRANCH == $DEF_BRANCH
  stage: upload
  before_script:
    - *pre_script_git_install
  tags:
    - run_docker_s
  image: curlimages/curl:latest
  script:
    - |
      curl --header "TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" --upload-file "${PATH}/debug/app-debug-${VERSION}.apk" "${PACKAGE_URL}/${VERSION}/app-debug-${BUILD_VERSION}.apk"
  needs:
    - job: assembleDebug
      artifacts: true
```

The `pre_script_git_install` in pre_script contains:

```
  - apt update
  - apt install -y git
```

Is there any possibility to add/install git to curlimage?

Comment: As far as I can see, the curl image is based on busybox and doesn't contain a package manager. If you want an image with both git and curl, you might be better off to start with something like an Alpine base image and install both git and curl on that.